# Formula added with Openpyxl breaks spreadsheet

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I wrote a script that extracts data from old 'afp' files and pastes it into Excel spreadsheet. Recently I tried to add a formula to one of the columns but doing that corrupts Excel spreadsheet. Any idea why this formula would cause this?:

```
sh.cell(row=2, column=8).value = '=IF([@Dess]>0,[@[Accnt Number]]&"D"&[@Dess],[@[Accnt Number]]&"C"&[@Css])'
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: I suspect that the formula is actually serialised slightly differently to how you write it in Excel. I suggest you create a sample XLSX file, unzip it and look at exactly how the formula is written in the XML.

Comment: @CharlieClark You were right. The formula was slightly different in XML! If you will change your comment to an answer, I will be happy to mark it as an answer! And thank you!